# Selenium Wrapper to randomly select an element from a dropDown ( the location (xpath, css, ...) of the dropdown is provided)?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to make selenium wrapper in order to randomly select test parameters, 
the random values can be selected from a dropdown for instance ....

Comment: Post your relevant HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Create list for all possible values from drop down for example you have drop down for country so your list will look like

```
country = ['Australia', 'INDIA', 'CANADA', 'etc']
```

Make list using Visible text from DOM.
Use choice function to select randomly

```
.select_by_visible_text(random.choice(country ))
```

Another option is using index

```
country = Select(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//xpath'))
country .select_by_index(randint(0, len(country .options) - 1))
```

Hope this helps